# How do I avoid errors when parsing a .csv file in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a .csv file that contains two columns: Ticker (the company ticker name) and Earnings (the corresponding company's earnings). When I read the file using the following code:

```
f = open('earnings.csv', 'r')
earnings = f.read()
```

The result when I run `print earnings` looks like this (it's a single string):

```
Ticker;Earnings
AAPL;52131400000
TSLA;-911214000
AMZN;583841600
```

I use the following code to split the string by the break line character (\n), followed by splitting each resulting line by the semi-colon character:

```
earnings_list = earnings.split('\n')
string_earnings = []
for string in earnings_list:
    colon_list = string.split(';')
    string_earnings.append(colon_list)
```

The result is a list of lists where each list contains the company's ticker at index[0] and its earnigns at index[1], like such:

```
[['Ticker', 'Earnings\r\r'], ['AAPL', '52131400000\r\r'], ['TSLA', '-911214000\r\r'], ['AMZN', '583841600\r\r']]
```

Now, I want to convert the earnings at index[1] of each list -which are currently strings- intro integers. So I first remove the first list containing the column names:

```
headless_earnings = string_earnings[1:]
```

Afterwards I try to loop over the resulting list to convert the values at index[1] of each list into integers with the following:

```
numerical = []
for i in headless_earnings:
    num = int(i[1])
    numerical.append(num)
```

I get the following error:

```
num = int(i[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How is that index out of range?

Comment: Setting aside the fact there's a `csv` module specifically designed so you don't have to do manual splitting, why not add `print(i)` right before the line causing the error and see what Python thinks `i` actually is?

Comment: Thanks, I know about the `csv` module, I was trying to get a deeper understanding of what happens under the hood. I did try that, when done individually for each line of code inside the loop, the output is the one I expect. When I run the loop as a whole the error shows up.

Comment: Well, no.  If `int(i[1])` is throwing an IndexError, then `i` does not have an element #1, so it's not true that if you add `print(i)` before it you'll see a list with two elements.

Comment: It's 100% sure your list does not contain exactly `[['Ticker', 'Earnings\r\r'], ['AAPL', '52131400000\r\r'], ['TSLA', '-911214000\r\r'], ['AMZN', '583841600\r\r']]` otherwise the rest of your code would work. I'd really bet the error comes from a last `\n` in your file, that leads `split()` to add an empty `['']` in `headless_earnings`, as explained in my answer (have you tried it?)

Comment: @zezollo You where correct. That empty `[" "]` was what caused the error. After applying the corrections the loop ran without problems. Sorry, I tried upvoting your answer but I don't have enought reputation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! You can still accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly mishandle the end of lines.

If I try your code with this string: "Ticker;Earnings\r\r\nAAPL;52131400000\r\r\nTSLA;-911214000\r\r\nAMZN;583841600" it works.

But with this one: "Ticker;Earnings\r\r\nAAPL;52131400000\r\r\nTSLA;-911214000\r\r\nAMZN;583841600\r\r\n" it doesn't.

Explanation: `split` creates a last list item containing only `['']`. So at the end, python tries to access `[''][1]`, hence the error.

So a very simple workaround would be to remove the last '\n' (if you're sure it's a '\n', otherwise you might have surprises).

You could write this:

```
earnings_list = earnings[:-1].split('\n')
```

this will fix your error.

If you want to be sure you remove a last '\n', you can write:

```
earnings_list = earnings[:-1].split('\n') if earnings[-1] == '\n' else earnings.split('\n')
```

EDIT: test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

earnings = "Ticker;Earnings\r\r\nAAPL;52131400000\r\r\nTSLA;-911214000\r\r\nAMZN;583841600\r\r\n"

earnings_list = earnings[:-1].split('\n') if earnings[-1] == '\n' else earnings.split('\n')
string_earnings = []
for string in earnings_list:
    colon_list = string.split(';')
    string_earnings.append(colon_list)

headless_earnings = string_earnings[1:]

#print(headless_earnings)

numerical = []
for i in headless_earnings:
    num = int(i[1])
    numerical.append(num)

print numerical
```

Output:

```
nico@ometeotl:~/temp$ ./test_script2.py 
[52131400000, -911214000, 583841600]
```

Comment: As pointed out by DSM, using the csv module you would avoid to reinvent the wheel.